# I need help on how to get a lower sized string from a bigger string? in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, resize, overflow

My problem could also translate to stopping a buffer from overflowing;

1st strategy

```
char first[40];
char g[] = "     Level %d      %d Fruit    %d:%d      ";
char d[41] = {0};   
strncpy(d, g, 40);
if(strlen(d) < 40) {
for(i = strlen(d); i < 40; i++) {
d[i] = ' ';
}
}
n = sprintf(first, d, gol, gift, minutes, secs );
```

I Print my n onto the game's screen, I get my text and some unknown characters following, which means there is a buffer overflow somewhere.

2nd strategy;

```
char first[40];
char b[40];
strncpy(b, g, sizeof(b));
fgets(b, 40, stdin);            // of b[40] = '\0' also fails            
n = sprintf(first, b, gol, gift, minutes, secs );
```

using " b[40] = '\0' ", I Print my n onto the game's screen, I get my text and some unknown characters following, which means there is a buffer overflow somewhere. using " fgets " crashes the game right away, even if g is 40 characters as of now, yet i want to increase it later

For both strategies, If I actually just put "g" in the " sprintf " statement, it does what I want except when I increase it to more than 40 characters. Sorry that I can't post the whole game code because its 4000 lines long split in 10 files.

I wold appreciate a completely different way of getting a string of only 40 characters from a string of more characters without leaving junk. The string has to be manually typed into the code, not input from user, it doesn't have to be declared like I declared "g".

THANKS

Comment: Of course `char b[40];  ... b[40] = '\0'` fails as `b[40]` is outside the range of `char b[40]`.  Everything after that is irrelevant.

Comment: `sprintf(first, b, gol, gift, minutes, secs );` certainly prints outside the range of `first`.

Comment: basically i couldn't do b[39] = '\0' because it would be taking part of the string. But anyway, i changed my code, so i no longer badly need an answer. Uu may turn your comment into an answer

Comment: Suggest you post you own best answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I found was that using " b[40] = '\0' " gives you a correct answer. But if you are using it in for loops, you have to keep track of when you hit a null '\0' to break. which would mean you reached the end. I didn't realize I had a working answer until a day afterwards.

Anyway, my TA ended up telling me that I was doing a lot more than I was asked, i.e I never needed to do this.